# Digital Ocean hosting not allowing to read file using simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, linux, digital-ocean

I am trying to read an RSS feed using the following code on a Digital Ocean host using PHP 5.4:

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
 $rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.filmfare.com/feeds/feeds-news.xml');
        echo 'RSS '.$rss;
foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        // handle errors here
var_dump($error);
    }
libxml_clear_errors();
?>
```

The code is just returning

```
RSS object(LibXMLError)#2 (6) { ["level"]=> int(1) ["code"]=> int(1549) ["column"]=> int(0) ["message"]=> string(78) "failed to load external entity "http://www.filmfare.com/feeds/feeds-news.xml" " ["file"]=> string(0) "" ["line"]=> int(0) } bool(false)
```

The same code when I am running on a Go Daddy host with PHP 5.3, is returning perfect result.

I have checked and following settings are same in `php.ini` on both the hosts

```
allow_url_fopen=On
allow_url_include = Off
```

I then tried the following CURL snippet as well,

```
<?php
$source='http://www.filmfare.com/feeds/feeds-news.xml';
$rcUrlHandle = curl_init($source);
curl_setopt($rcUrlHandle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$sData = curl_exec($rcUrlHandle);
if(curl_errno($rcUrlHandle))
{
   echo 1;
    print_r(curl_getinfo($rcUrlHandle));
    curl_close($rcUrlHandle);
}
else
{
    echo 2 ;
    print_r($sData);
    curl_close($rcUrlHandle);
}
?>
```

Digital Ocean still returns nothing whereas Go Daddy is returning perfect fine. Any idea?

```
allow_url_fopen     On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
```

Comment: If you do a [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), what value shows for allow_url_fopen?

Comment: Can you try to `wget` or `curl` the feed and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that DigitalOcean IP has not been whitelisted by the end party. Initiated the process with them and should be through in few hours. Thanks everyone.